# Autofac registrations are conflicting between multiple implementations

Tags: asp.net, autofac

Here in my Autofac registration I have these registrations:

```
builder.RegisterType<MemcachedClient>()
       .As<IMemcachedClient>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<RequestCacheManager>()
       .As<ICacheManager>()
       .Named<ICacheManager>("cache_per_request").InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MemcachedManager>()
       .As<ICacheManager>()
       .Named<ICacheManager>("cache_static_mem").InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MemoryCacheManager>()
       .As<ICacheManager>()
       .Named<ICacheManager>("cache_static").SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<StoreOrderService>().As<IStoreOrderService>()
       .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("cache_per_request"))
        .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

As you can see I am registering 3 different CacheManagers but for the StoreOrderService I am forcing that implementation to be "Request" based i.e. caching per request.

Now I also have this registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomerHelper>().As<ICustomerHelper>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

The CustomerHelper includes a CacheManager in it's constructor. I want the CustomerHelper to use EITHER the `MemoryCacheManager` OR the `MemcachedManager` but I do not want it to use the cache per request strategy.

However because the `StoreOrderService` is called first, and then my `CustomerHelper`, my `CustomerHelper` ends up with a "Cache per request" `ICacheManager`. How do I force the `CustomerHelper` to not use this "Cache per request" `ICacheManager`?

Comment: Why don't you just provide a `ResolvedParameter.ForNamed` for your `CustomerHelper` with the correct `ICacheManager`? So `builder.RegisterType<CustomerHelper>().As<ICustomerHelper>()
       .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("cache_static_mem"))`
        .InstancePerHttpRequest();`